# Symfony crawler select OPTION in SELECT list without FORM

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, symfony-panther

I am crawling a website that has a SELECT that are freestanding with no FORM parent and no NAME, only ID.

```
<select id="ff-select-Choice" class="ff-form-control">
    <option value="">please select</option>
    <option value="val1">first</option>
    <option value="val2">second</option>
    <option value="val3">third</option>
</select>
```

I am able to select it with

```
$myInput = $crawler->filter('#ff-select-Choice');
```

and

```
$myInput->click();
```

will open the list, but how can I select a value in the list by value or name ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like

```
$myInput = $crawler->filterXPath(".//select[@id='ff-select-Choice']//option[@value='val2']");
```

and see if it works.

Comment: That worked, had to add a $myInput->click(); afterwards.
So the filterXPath seems to open the pulldown and select the value and just needs a click.  My solution opened the pulldown, but was never able to select any values.

Thank you !

Comment: Done.  Was actually trying to do that yesterday, but could not find how to do it :|  Had to google to find out :)  Could have been better GUI there....